# connect remote MQ using Java?

Tags: java, connection, communication, mq

Friends,
        I installed IBM explorer 7.1 which have server and GUI. Locally I connected the queue using inter process communication. Now I need to connect the server QM from remote machine using java standalone program.
In  server I have created a queue, port and server channel. when I trying to connect using host name , unable to get the connection. Is this the right way?. else I have to install  client where I tried connect that server.but getting error code 2035 when i run that java program. listener and queue manage is running in remote machine. Some forum i seen that AMQCLCHL.TAB file using for client connection. I had confusion whether i have to use that for client connection. if yes how i can use that?

Comment: Have you provided authentication details(security credentials) and do you have authorization to access that queue?

Comment: You will need to tell us what error or exception you are getting. Without that it's difficult to guess what's going on. On the remote machine where you want to run your Java application you must install MQ Client. It's available for free download at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24031412.

Comment: using mq explorer i have created queue manager,channel. but getting error code 2035 when i run that java program. listener and queue manage is running in remote machine. Some forum i seen that AMQCLCHL.TAB file using for client connection. I had confusion whether i have to use that for client connection. if yes how i can use that? 
my sample program 
MQEnvironment.hostname = "192.168.2.42"; 
MQEnvironment.channel = "CHANNEL1"; 
MQEnvironment.port = 1414; 
MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY,MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT); try{ qManager = new MQQueueManager(qMngrStr);}